# Need Excel macro to open VNC to a machine name specified in the Active Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create and run an Excel macro, that will open VNC Viewer, and then connect to the Machine name that is specified in the Active Cell of the open Workbook.

If I manually put the specific machine name into the quotes (shown in Working Example), it will do what I want, but I need the user to highlight a cell, run the macro and the VNC will open just like in the working example below.

**Working Example:**

---

```
Sub VNC()
   Shell ("C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe H112-R2S2")
End Sub
```

---

**NON-Working Example:**

---

```
Sub VNC()
    Dim txt As String
    txt = ActiveCell.Value
    RetVal = Shell("C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe " & txt)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give more details about what is not working in your non-working example? E.g. does it fail silently, throw an error message, etc. Are you getting anything in `RetVal`. For debugging it might help to add the line `debug.print txt` before the call to Shell to see what is getting fed to Shell.

Comment: `RetVal = Shell("""C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe"" """ & txt & """")`

Comment: ...usiually a good idea to quote anything which has (or might have) a space in it.

Comment: In the Working Example, I have given the machine name, so it knows what machine to VNC to.
In the Non-Working Example, I believe have given it a variable, so it knows what machine to VNC to, based on the highlighted cell in the current spreadsheet.
I am no near the machine again til next week, but I know the error number is 53.
At which point nothing additional happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a bit strange. What happens if you create the string first and pass in the while string?

```
Sub VNC()
    Dim txt As String
    txt = "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe " & ActiveCell.Value
    RetVal = Shell(txt)
End Sub
```

Comment: This did the trick! I was just getting into the "RetVal" thing, but I'm not quite so skilled yet. This did exactly what I needed to do. Thank you!